# Display picture with different height? HTML

Tags: html, image, displayobject

So I'm trying to insert pictures with different height next to eachother and under each other like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgH1O.png

I know how to put them next to each other with the same height, but whenever I try to put them next to each other with different heights, IMG1's bottom line goes down to IMG4's bottom line. How do I make it like this??
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually by floating 2 columns next to each other and filling these columns equally with images.

Or you can use a plugin like Grid-A-Licious which is responsive as well.
It will build your grid layout for you.
http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/